# SQL Server 2008 active URL link

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

There is any possibility to store some links to a location from a server in a in a SQL Server  2008 database?

I have some rows in a table and for each of them I have a pdf.

I want to create a column in which to store the link to this PDF which will be placed on a server location.

My question is how could I make this link clickable (active), there is any specific type column for links?

Thank you!

Comment: There's no specific *client* for SQL Server. The closest to a standard is Management Studio, but it's not really intended to be used for general data entry, editing and viewing (it's intended for administration tasks, ad-hoc queries, etc). So, whilst building a suitable client application, you're free to add whatever features you like for formatting one of your columns. There's nothing built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a feature directly in SQL.

On the front end this would be a hypelink.

It depends on the front end

ASP.NET DataGrid:

[HyperLinkColumn Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkcolumn.aspx)

In WPF:

[DataGridHyperlinkColumn Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridhyperlinkcolumn.aspx)

In SQL you would just store the link location as a char or varchar.

Answer (score 3):

In the database, just simply store the URL as a string - `varchar(200)` or whatever works for you.

Making that URL clickable is the job of a **front-end application**, e.g. your ASP.NET or PHP  or whatever app that displays that data.

This is not something SQL Server should be concerned about -

So **no** - there is **no specific datatype** to make a column *clickable* in SQL Server directly.